# How to fix Redirect URL is not valid ! error when trying to access wp-login.php?

Tags: wordpress

When I try to access the wp-login.php page, I get the following error:

"Redirect URL is not valid !"

I've tried everything [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-wordpress-login-page-refreshing-and-redirecting-issue/)

- clear cookies
- deactivate all plugins
- revert back to the Default Theme
- delete .htaccess file
- update site URL

But none of the above did anything. I thought that deactivating all plugins would solve the issue because not too long before this issue started I had just installed and begun configuring the WP Cassify plugin. However, when I went to rename the plugins directory, I did not see the WP Cassify plugin listed, which is weird.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what else I can try to fix this issue?

Comment: can we have a link to the site ? and how did you desactivate all plugin if you don't have access to login page ?

Comment: Did you just move hosting or domains?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I disabled plugins by renaming the plugins folder on the server

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by renaming the wp-cassify plugin (and essentially deactivating it by doing so).

That simple!